# cant build unity project with both facebook sdk and audiance network sdk in it

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-audience-network

When I import both audience network sdk and facebook sdk in my unity project it fails to build the project.

I tried deleting all unity packages using package manager.

updated jdk8_11 and ndk16b

updated unity to 2019.1.9

But nothing worked

I know the problem lies within facebook and not unity or anything else because

1. project builds just fine with just audience network sdk in it.
2. project builds just fine with just facebook sdk in it.

The Build fails only when I import both the packages in the project.

I get following error when I import both package in unity:

> PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the
>   same name Facebook.Unity.Android.dll included for the current
>   platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per
>   platform. Assembly path: {0}
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorBuildRules.CreateTargetAssemblies
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] customScriptAssemblies,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] precompiledAssemblies) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorBuildRules.cs:221)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.UpdateCustomTargetAssemblies
>   () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:672)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsonContents
>   (System.String[] paths, System.String[] contents, System.String[]
>   guids) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:892)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.SetAllCustomScriptAssemblyJsonContents
>   (System.String[] allAssemblyJsonPaths, System.String[]
>   allAssemblyJsonContents, System.String[] guids) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:241)

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I used only UnityFacebookSDK, got the same error message, I've posted my answer in the Unity forum here [Link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2018-3-precompiledassemblyexception-multiple-precompiled-assemblies-with-the-same-name.600958/), I paste the answer here too :

I got the same issue when import the UnityFacebookSDK to project. Turn out there are duplicated libraries, they have two Facebook.Unity.Android.dlls and two Facebook.Unity.IOS.dlls. Here my solution:

- Goto FacebookSDK/Plugins/Android : delete the Facebook.Unity.IOS.dll in that folder
- Goto FacebookSDK/Plugins/IOS : delete the Facebook.Unity.Android.dll
- Exit Unity
- Goto the project Library folder: delete PackageCache and ScriptAssemblies folder
- Restart Unity to let it rebuild the two folders we just delete

It worked for me, hope it'll help you.